# Embed fields URL discord js

Tags: discord, discord.js, embed

How to put url from field to config.json. But only the url, not the text. From this

```
.addField("**hi**", `[**Hello**](https:iegbshd)`)
```

to this

```
const { hello } = require('../config.json')

.addField("**hi**", `[**Hello**](hello)`)
```

config.json
{
"hello": "https:iegbshd"
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use variables inside of `` quotes you need to put them into `${}` and get such code:

```js
.addField("**hi**", `[**Hello**](${hello})`)
```